# RQT Reconfigure - no plugin found

Tags: ros, rqt-reconfigure, plugin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I try to run:

```
rosrun rqt_reconfigure rqt_reconfigure
```

and I get:

```
CompositePluginProvider.discover() could not discover plugins from provider "<class 'rqt_gui.rospkg_plugin_provider.RospkgPluginProvider'>": 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qt_gui/composite_plugin_provider.py", line 58, in discover
    plugin_descriptors = plugin_provider.discover(discovery_data)
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_gui/ros_plugin_provider.py", line 65, in discover
    plugin_descriptors += self._parse_plugin_xml(package_name, plugin_xml)
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_gui/ros_plugin_provider.py", line 141, in _parse_plugin_xml
    module_name, class_from_class_type = attributes['class_type'].rsplit('.', 1)
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

qt_gui_main() found no plugin matching "rqt_reconfigure"
```

How can I solve this?

EDIT:

> rqt --list-plugins

returns:

```
CompositePluginProvider.discover() could not discover plugins from provider "<class 'rqt_gui.rospkg_plugin_provider.RospkgPluginProvider'>":
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qt_gui/composite_plugin_provider.py", line 58, in discover
    plugin_descriptors = plugin_provider.discover(discovery_data)
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_gui/ros_plugin_provider.py", line 65, in discover
    plugin_descriptors += self._parse_plugin_xml(package_name, plugin_xml)
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_gui/ros_plugin_provider.py", line 141, in _parse_plugin_xml
    module_name, class_from_class_type = attributes['class_type'].rsplit('.', 1)
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

rqt_dep.ros_pack_graph.RosPackGraph
rqt_image_view/ImageView
rqt_py_console.py_console.PyConsole
rqt_rviz/RViz
rqt_shell.shell.Shell
rqt_web.web.Web
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/166851/rqt-reconfigure---no-plugin-found/) by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1247 on 2014-05-19

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2014-05-19**:
Do you have `rqt_reconfigure` package installed on your machine? What does this command return? `$ rospack find rqt_reconfigure`?

**Comment by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on 2014-06-10**:
Of course, yes!

It returns:
/opt/ros/hydro/share/rqt_reconfigure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How about running `rqt`, a container GUI that can host multiple rqt plugins on, and choose rqt_reconfigure from `Plugin` menu, like:

```
$ rqt &
(An rqt window opens. Then choose plugin.)
```

instead of directly launching an rqt plugin by `$ rosrun rqt_reconfigure rqt_reconfigure` as you mentioned.

Or, if that doesn't help, try:

```
$ rqt --force-discover
(Then choose plugin.)
```

If this doesn't help yet, tell us the version you're using:

```
$ rosversion qt_gui && rosversion rqt_gui
```

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2014-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2017-07-15**:
I just ran into a very similar error and this my own answer helped myself.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-15**:
yeah, I've had that before :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just delete ~/.config/ros.org/rqt_gui.ini.

---

Originally posted by [byeongkyu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4428/byeongkyu/) with karma: 126 on 2014-06-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 10

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on 2014-07-03**:
Doesn't help. Sorry! :(